# I want to remove the arrow sign from my last <li> using CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I have my product page. The breadcrumbs over there are being displayed in this format

`Home > TORNADO > Chicken Smoked Pizza >`

I want it to be in this format

`Home > TORNADO > Chicken Smoked Pizza`

I do not want **>** at the end.

How will I achieve this?

This is my css

```
.breadcrumb {
margin: 20px 0;
padding: 10px 0;
}
.breadcrumb i {
    font-size: 15px;
}
.breadcrumb .fa {
    color: #111;
}
.breadcrumb > li {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.breadcrumb > li a {
    color: #888888;
}
.breadcrumb > li a:hover {
    color: #111;
}
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
    content: '';
    padding: 0;
}
.breadcrumb > li:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: -5px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-right: 1px solid #BBB;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.pagination {
    margin: 0;
}
```

and this is my controller where i am creating the breadcrumbs

```
$data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $this->model_multirestaurant_restaurant->getRestaurantName($this->session->data['r_id']),
                'href' => $this->url->link('restaurant/listing/detail', '&id=' . $this->session->data['r_id'])
            );

            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $product_info['name'],
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', $url . '&product_id=' . $this->request->get['product_id'])
            );
```

and this is my loop in tpl file

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Because the `>` is apparently being generated by CSS, not PHP. He has only just decided to let us know that. Not once does it mention that the > is generated by CSS in his question.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid Oh smeg, it's the rotated border. I totally overlooked that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use `preg_replace` with `$`

```
$string = 'Home > TORNADO > Chicken Smoked Pizza >';
echo preg_replace('/>$/', '', $string);// echoes Home > TORNADO > Chicken Smoked Pizza
```

See demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e458dfd463543415ad59b31a1547844af4cf6b2e)

**EDIT**

```
ul.breadcrumb li:last-child {
    content: none;
}
```

Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FVHjG/11/)

Comment: $data['breadcrumbs'] is an array and this is not a string, It is displayed through loop. I want my last `li` not to display >

Comment: you can capture to a string and then echo. whats wrong in that??

Comment: The > is getting generated from css. I want it to be handled from my css.

Comment: No. I want it to be handled within css.

Comment: Then why question is tagged with `php`??

Comment: @AliZia - then why don't you write that in your question so people can help you better!!!

Comment: My bad. I deleted it.

Comment: @AliZia check my answer.

Comment: Bro I saw the link. When I use your code, All my breadcrumbs disappear and only `> > >` is displayed.

Comment: i think small change is required, add your breadcrumbs with html.

Comment: @AliZia i have used same class for `li` make sure you change the css.

Comment: `ul.breadcrumb li:last-child { content: none; }` - The ">" is not added via `content`, it's added via `border` - setting the `content` to `none` will not remove the ">" but will... remove the content... and as you've not used `:after`, it will remove the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding it via css (as confirmed after some comments/answers), then remove it via css:

```
.breadcrumb > li:last-child:after {
    border:none;
}
```

More info on `:last-child` :

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alast-child

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdfhpmvv/)

Answer (score 0):

If the `>` was in the text, use PHP `trim()` (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php))

**edit**: I see you use a loop now and that you generate the `>` using css.

You now put the `>` using css, I would suggest to do it with text inside the loop. See my updated answer (added `>` as text in the loop).

To fix it using only `css` see **@Niranjan N Raju** his answer.

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <?php 
    $bcount = count($breadcrumbs);
    for ($i=0; $i<$bcount; $i++){
        if ($i<$bcount-1){
        ?>
         <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumbs[$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumbs[$i]['text']; ?> > </a></li>
        <?php
        }
        else{
        ?>
         <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumbs[$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumbs[$i]['text']; ?></a></li>
        <?php
        }
    } ?>
  </ul>
```

---

I think it is more pretty to inline the html though:

```
<?php echo '<ul class="breadcrumb">';
    $bcount = count($breadcrumbs);
    for ($i=0; $i<$bcount; $i++){
        if ($i<$bcount-1){
           echo '<li><a href="'. $breadcrumbs[$i]['href'].'">'.$breadcrumbs[$i]['text'].' > </a></li>';
        }
        else{
          echo '<li><a href="'.$breadcrumbs[$i]['href'];.'">'.$breadcrumbs[$i]['text'].'</a></li>';
        }
    }
  echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: The '>' is being generated from css. This is not being countered here by your code.

Comment: ooooh.. its css.. my apologies, I thought it was in the text variable. I would advice not to do it in css.

Comment: No problem. That is why I displayed my css code because the > is being displayed from css.

Comment: Ok, I made my answer the non-css solution, for the css answer see the other answer from @Niranjan.

Comment: I guess I will have to go with the non css solution :)

Comment: Ok, made a small mistake though, fixed it now. `$breadcrumb` should be `$breadcrumbs[$i]` in my code.